# Link url to angular app using routers

Tags: angular

I have created forgot password page using Angular 4 where the user enter email address so that I will send a link to respective email address which has path and token attached to it.

By click on that link redirects to set new password page.

Below is my link pattern where the user received in his mail,

http://192.168.2.90:4200/resetpassword/mLdeO_Ve7S11Ikh4yqeU_qKoBMUUY5ID_1507804372

When I click on this link a empty page is displayed in fact navigation or routing is not happening properly .

My question is that, it is not redirecting to reset password page.

And also in app.module.ts i have configured the routing as below,

**const appRoutes:Routes=[

{

 path:'resetpassword/:token',

 component:ResetPasswordComponent,

},
 ]**

Can any one please help me out to get the reset password page by clicking on link received in the email address.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see any messages in the console?

Comment: this is the message I got in console   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: perhaps you are missing /#/resetpassword

Comment: when i copy and paste that url it is working but when I click the link in my mail it is redirecting to login page

Comment: can u please help me here when i type the path in url it is loading but when I click the link in my mail it is redirecting to login page

Comment: What is checked before the redirection to the loginpage? Perhaps some authentication inconsistency